# Plotly Sankey Diagram Python

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id|course|sem
1|a|1
2|b|2
3|c|2
1|b|2
```

I want to plot a sankey diagram for semester to semester transition using plotly.(for eg.,sem1->sem2->sem3). The flow indicates the count of students taking a particular subject from one semester to other semester.How can I do it?
I have tried the following code:

```
data_trace = dict(
    type='sankey',
    domain = dict(
      x =  [0,1],
      y =  [0,1]
    ),
    orientation = "h",
    valueformat = ".0f",
    node = dict(
      pad = 10,
      thickness = 30,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0
      ),
      label =  df_sankey.index.dropna(how='any'),
      #color = df_sankey['Color']
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = df_sankey.index.dropna( how='any'),
      target = df_sankey.index.dropna( how='any'),
      value = df_sankey['sem1'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
      #color = df['Link Color'].dropna(axis=0, how='any'),
  )
)

layout =  dict(
    title = "Student Semester Flow",
    height = 772,
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    ),    
)

fig7 = dict(data=[data_trace], layout=layout)
```

I did not get the expected output.This is the transition flow I am expecting
[Sankey Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEqXD.png)

Comment: Without an excerpt of you dataframe and a clarification of what each column means, I doubt you will get an answer.

Comment: @sentence First column in data corresponds to student id,second column corresponds to course name and the third one represents the semester in which the student took the subject